# Why is my asynch mongodb query function hanging?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, async-await

First of all, please forgive me if this is a duplicate, I am new to coding and Javascript in general.

I have an async function that queries mongodb based on an objects passed in the function call.  The function executes, and returns the results to a callback function which logs the results to the console, and then hangs.  Ultimately, I want to take the results of the async query and then do something with them outside the original async function. I am not understanding why it hangs after it logs to the console.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
let fObj = {
    field : {},
    limit : 100
}

let cObj = {
    dbName : 'myNewDatabase',
    colName : 'newCollection'
}

async function findDoc(cObj,fObj) {
    const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
    const client = new MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
    try {
        await client.connect();
        const db = client.db(cObj.dbName);
        const col = db.collection(cObj.colName);
        console.log(`Connection Made to ${db.databaseName} database.`);
        return await col.find(fObj.field).limit(fObj.limit).toArray();
        client.close();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.stack);
    }
};

findDoc(cObj,fObj).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

The code executes, and logs the results to the console, but then hangs.  I have to ctrl-c out to get it to end.  What am I missing?

Comment: close client before return, or better do it in a finally block

Comment: Attempting to close the client in a finally block results in an unhandled promise rejection, and the app hangs.

Comment: No return in a finally block not the close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppouse you're running your code with NodeJs. This implies that you have a promise hanging up, which keeps the server running. I assume this is because your connection to the DB is still open after you have found the document.

You need to move your `client.close();` statement above the `return` statement, because it is never reached otherwise and your server will hang up forever.

Your code will look like this in the end:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
let fObj = {
    field : {},
    limit : 100
}

let cObj = {
    dbName : 'myNewDatabase',
    colName : 'newCollection'
}

async function findDoc(cObj,fObj) {
    const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
    const client = new MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
    try {
        await client.connect();
        const db = client.db(cObj.dbName);
        const col = db.collection(cObj.colName);
        console.log(`Connection Made to ${db.databaseName} database.`);
        const result = await col.find(fObj.field).limit(fObj.limit).toArray();
        client.close();
        return result;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.stack);
    }
};

findDoc(cObj,fObj).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Also, I advise you to enclose your whole async function's body into the try clause. This way you will be able to effectively intercept any error. Imagine your `new MongoClient` failed to instantiate - you would end up with an uncaught error inside a promise, which isn't very nice.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  Got more work to do with promises it seems.